Understanding the definiton of weakly open sest and weak convergence
I am learning about weak and weak* topology. In the book I am reading the following is mentioned

Definiton (weak topology) If X is a LCS, the weak topology on X, is
the topoloty defined by the family of seminorms $\mathcal{P}:=\{p_f:f
> \in X^*\}$, where $p_f(x):=|f(x)|$.
So a subset U of X is weakly open iff for every $x_0 \in I$ there
is $\epsilon>0$ and there are $f_1,...,f_n \in X^*$ such that
$\cap_{k=1}^n \{x \in X : |p_{f_k}(x-x_0)|< \epsilon \} \subseteq U$.

Question 1:
I do not understand the comment after the definition, because given a family of seminorms $\mathcal{P}$ a set U is open (by definition) if for every $x_0 \in U$ there are $p_1,...,p_n\in \mathcal{P}$ and $\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_n>0$ such that $\cap_{k=1}^n
\{x \in X: p_k(x-x_0)<\epsilon_k \} \subseteq U$.
So, my first question is, why is it necessary in the general case to have $\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_n>0$, but in the case of the weak convergence we can reduce it to only $\epsilon$?
Question 2:
After the section with the comment on weakly open set U it is mentioned that

A net ${x_i}$ in X converges weakly to $x_0$ iff $f(x_i) \rightarrow
> f(x_0)$ for every $f \in X*$.

The definition I know about net convergence is:
A net $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ converges to $x$ in $(X,\tau)$ iff
$\forall U \in \tau:x \in U \Rightarrow \exists i_0 \in I: \forall i_0 \leq i: x_i \in U$.
I do not see how those two are connected. How does one get the notion of weakly convergence?


Consider the minimum of $\varepsilon_k$. 2. A neighbourhood of the limit is given by finitely many $f$, use that the index set of the net is directed so that, for the finitely many $i_f\in I$ you $i_0\in I$ bigger than all $i_f$.

